# Django templates doesn't load the content of child templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views, django-settings

I'm working on a project using Django(1.11) in which I have created a `base.html` template in which I have defined all the universal HTML code of my project like required CSS and js files.

But when I extend this template in my child templates it only loads the base template not the content of child template.

Here's what I have tried:

**base.html:**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{% static 'images/kit/free/apple-icon.png' %}"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="{% static 'images/kit/free/favicon.png' %}"/>
    <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Roboto+Slab:400,700|Material+Icons"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/material-kit.css' %}">
    {% block title %}
      <title> Docrest Web Gui </title>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body class="signup-page">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-color-on-scroll navbar-transparent    fixed-top  navbar-expand-lg " color-on-scroll="100" id="sectionsNav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-translate">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Docrest Gui </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="dropdown nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            <i class="material-icons">apps</i> Components
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-with-icons">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="material-icons">layers</i> All Components
                            </a>
                            <a href="http://demos.creative-tim.com/material-kit/docs/2.0/getting-started/introduction.html" class="dropdown-item">
                                <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i> Documentation
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {% if not user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'users:login' %}">
                            <i class="material-icons">exit_to_app</i> Login
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="{% url 'users:signup' %}" target="_blank" data-original-title="Register to Deploy code!">
                            <i class="material-icons">settings_input_hdmi</i> Signup
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    {% endif %}
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="{% url 'users:signup' %}" target="_blank" data-original-title="Register to Deploy code!">
                            <i class="material-icons">settings_input_hdmi</i> Dashboard
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="https://www.facebook.com/CreativeTim" target="_blank" data-original-title="Like us on Facebook">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="bottom" href="https://www.instagram.com/CreativeTimOfficial" target="_blank" data-original-title="Follow us on Instagram">
                            <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="page-header header-filter" data-parallax="true" style=" background-image: url('../assets/img/kit/profile_city.jpg'); ">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1 class="title">Your Story Starts With Us.</h1>
                    <h4>Every landing page needs a small description after the big bold title, that&apos;s why we added this text here. Add here all the information that can make you or your product create the first impression.</h4>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}

{% block js %}
    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/core/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/core/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap-material-design.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--  Plugin for Date Time Picker and Full Calendar Plugin  -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/moment.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--    Plugin for the Datepicker, full documentation here: https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker -->

    <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!--    Plugin for the Sliders, full documentation here: http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ -->

    <script src="{% static 'js/plugins/nouislider.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- Material Kit Core initialisations of plugins and Bootstrap Material Design Library -->
    <script src="{% static 'js/material-kit.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Here's an example child template **signup.html**:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block title %}
        <title> Signup </title>
    {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 ml-auto mr-auto">
                <div class="card card-signup">
                    <h2 class="card-title text-center">Register</h2>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-5 ml-auto">
                                <div class="info info-horizontal">
                                    <div class="icon icon-rose">
                                        <i class="material-icons">timeline</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="description">
                                        <h4 class="info-title">Marketing</h4>
                                        <p class="description">
                                            We've created the marketing campaign of the website. It was a very
                                            interesting collaboration.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="info info-horizontal">
                                    <div class="icon icon-primary">
                                        <i class="material-icons">code</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="description">
                                        <h4 class="info-title">Fully Coded in HTML5</h4>
                                        <p class="description">
                                            We've developed the website with HTML5 and CSS3. The client has access to
                                            the code using GitHub.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="info info-horizontal">
                                    <div class="icon icon-info">
                                        <i class="material-icons">group</i>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="description">
                                        <h4 class="info-title">Built Audience</h4>
                                        <p class="description">
                                            There is also a Fully Customizable CMS Admin Dashboard for this product.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 mr-auto">
                                <div class="social text-center">
                                    <button class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-twitter">
                                        <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-dribbble">
                                        <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <button class="btn btn-just-icon btn-round btn-facebook">
                                        <i class="fa fa-facebook"> </i>
                                    </button>
                                    <h4> or be classical </h4>
                                </div>
                                <form class="form" method="" action="">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                                        <i class="material-icons">face</i>
                                                    </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name...">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                                        <i class="material-icons">mail</i>
                                                    </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email...">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                    <span class="input-group-text">
                                                        <i class="material-icons">lock_outline</i>
                                                    </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-control"/>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check">
                                        <label class="form-check-label">
                                            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" checked>
                                            <span class="form-check-sign">
                                                    <span class="check"></span>
                                                </span>
                                            I agree to the
                                            <a href="#something">terms and conditions</a>.
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-center">
                                        <a href="#pablo" class="btn btn-primary btn-round">Get Started</a>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

and here are the settings for Templates:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Here's how this template is rendered:

```
class SignUpView(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.SignUpForm
    template_name = 'users/signup.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('users:login')
    form_valid_message = 'User has been created successfully!'
    form_invalid_message = 'Something wrong'
```

The child template is rendered from a default login view of Django auth, but it only displays the content of the base template, the child template's contents why not loading?

I already have taken a look at all of related question but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: I have added the view code!

Comment: You need to do `{% extends "base.html" %}` not include. Include will put the base markup at the top of the page then the rest under it.

Comment: {% extends "base.html" %} is not working also!

Comment: @AbdulRehman ok, well it's a step in the right direction & proper use of template extension. So what actually gets rendered to the page now because "it only loads the base template not the content of child template" won't be true now you're extending the `base.html` blocks properly.

Comment: Hi @markwalker_, it's still loading the content only of **base.html** and the child template's content is not loading in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the templating language will like:

```
{% block head %}
    {% block title %} {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Try replacing it with the following in both files.

```
{% block title %} {% endblock %}
```

Also, you shouldn't need `{% load staticfile %}` if you have  `{% load static %}`

Comment: Hi @HenryM, it's still not loading the content of child template, as i have added only the `title` tag in `signup.html` template as `Signup` but it still displaying the title of base template.

Comment: Actually, I forgot to update the `base.html` code here but it should display the title of `signup.html` when I load this template. am I right?